# Brushed DC Motor - Driving Forwards With PWM AND Detecting Reverse Motion

Tags: operational-amplifier, pwm, brushed-dc-motor

[image: Test circuit]

I would like to drive a small 9V brushed DC motor using PWM from a micro-controller and came up with the standard circuit of: micro-controller PWM out (J1) connected to a mosfet gate with a current limiting resistor (R1) and pull down resistor (R2) and a fly-back diode (1N4001).

BUT! I would also like the motor to run freely in the reverse direction. So, I added a resistor (R3) in series with the flyback diode to prevent braking.

AND! I would like to detect when it is running in reverse without additional sensor. So, I added an op amp in open loop gain configuraton. This is "low" (saturated) when the motor is stopped / turning forward because the non-inverting input voltage is >= the inverting input. Then, the output goes "high" (saturated) when the motor is spun in reverse because of the back EMF raising the non-inverting voltage.

I arrived here somewhat by trail and error and using the components to hand but it seems to work and seems to make sense.

Am I missing something and is there a better way to do this?
What would be ideal values for the components? You can probably tell the bag of 10k was closest when I was doing my test; a dedicated comparator would probably be better than the general op amp I am using; and people always suggest Schottky as flyback diodes.

Thanks!